# How do I open a terminal with another user name?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, bashrc

Whenever I open the terminal, I want to login as another user (`another_user`). I tried putting the below in my .bashrc, but it prompts me for a password everytime I open the terminal.

```
# in .bashrc
su - another_user
```

Question: how do I pass `another_user`'s password as a text input in .bashrc so that I don't have to type it every time the terminal opens?

PS: don't worry about security issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Also... wouldn't it be easier to sign in as them? It seems a bit strange to sign into you, only to instantly sign in as them... perhaps you have [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1081494)?

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu 21.10, Kernel version: 5.13.0.

Comment: @cocomac, I appreciate your suggestion but that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me:

```
echo 'password_text' | sudo -S sleep 1 && sudo su - another_user
```

thanks!

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1351872/how-to-provide-password-directly-to-the-sudo-su-someuser-in-shell-scripting